# side scrolling clouds

Tags: java, android, android-emulator, libgdx

I have clouds that are scrolling left to right. I'm using an OrthographicCamera to do so. I was wondering, how would i adjust these clouds in order to cause them to move towards the screen, rather than from left to right? Could i still use the Orthographic camera to do so? How would i do this?

My code is as follows:

```
public void create() {  

        sky = new SkyFlux();

        //getting the height and width for setup purposes
        float w = Gdx.graphics.getWidth();
        float h = Gdx.graphics.getHeight();

        //setting up camera and batch
        camera = new OrthographicCamera(1, h/w);

        //setting up sky
        for(Texture texture:sky.getTexture())
            textures.add(texture);

        //Adding the sky related sprites
        for(Sprite sprite:sky.getSprite())
            skySprites.add(sprite);
}



public void render() {

        //clearing everything out
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 1, 1, 1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL10.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
        time += Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
        if(time > 1.0f)
            time = 0.0f;

        float speed = 1.0f;

        //Adjusting the speed of the sprites except the first sprite which is the base image.
        for(int i=1;i<skySprites.size();i++) {
            skySprites.get(i).setV(time+speed);
            skySprites.get(i).setV2(time);
            speed = speed+1.0f;
        }

        //setting up
        batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);

        //begging draw
        batch.begin();

        //items to be drawn
        //TODO: add other items to be drawn here
        for(Sprite sprite:skySprites)
            sprite.draw(batch);


        //ending draw 
        batch.end();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Orthographic projections by definition store no depth information. The only way you can make the appearance of clouds coming towards the screen is to increase the sprite size - but I advise against it.

You should use a non-orthographic projection and just use the z-axis.

Comment: Hmm, ok. Which type of camera would you suggest? ProjectionViewportCamera? Isometric? or Perspective?

Comment: I've used `libgdx` before with ProjectionViewportCamera (even for 2d games with minimal 3d elements like smoke puffs etc) with ease so I would suggest that.